# Adding a JS script to a Laravel page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to create my first Laravel site, but I can't figure out how to add a JS file to one of my pages.

I only want the JS file to be used on this page and no where else.

How do I get my page to load the JS file?

My directory structure is like so:

```
apply
    js
        myjsfile.js
    apply.blade.php
```

---

In my apply.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div id="applicationForm" class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

layouts.master file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head') 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            @include('includes.header')
        </div>
        @yield('content')
        <div id="footer">
            @include('includes.footer')
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

your `apply.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div id="applicationForm" class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
@stop

@section('myjsfile')
    <script src="js/myjsfile.js"><script>
@stop
```

your `layouts.master`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head') 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            @include('includes.header')
        </div>
        @yield('content')
        <div id="footer">
            @include('includes.footer')
        </div>
        </div>
    @yield('myjsfile')
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where would I put the @ section bit? I want all my JS files to load in the footer.